# Can't figure out what's causing the error here - React Native ToDo List App

Tags: react-native

my react native ToDo list app is crashing whenever I try to type in and add an item to the list with the + button. Attached are screenshots of the android emulator.

[Here's the initial look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRxN5.png)

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDb61.png)

I don't want to post a wall of text so here's the github link to the project: 
https://github.com/Accurac/todoApp2018/tree/master/todoApp
The only files edited were App.js, app/components/Main.js and app/components/Note.js

I feel like the main cause is this line:

```
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
      deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)} />
    });
```

Thanks for any help, I just have no idea what the issue is :/

Answer (score 1):

It will be `this.props.val.date` not `this.prop.val.date`. You missed `s` in `props`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe I didn't notice that

Comment: If this solves your issue, then you may accept this as the valid answer.